# Extract and edit token from response header - Galing and Scala

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

Can someone help? 
I'm saving response header with Bearer token value
Then I'm putting it to the new request header
How to convert 'id_token' to the proper format and paste to request?

**Graphic:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sN2f.jpg

**The response from login request:**

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Connection: close
date: Wed, 17 Jun 2020 06:29:34 GMT
x-powered-by: Express
access-control-allow-origin: https://admin-test-demo-se.skeleton.sh
vary: Origin
access-control-allow-credentials: true
content-length: 41
set-cookie: id_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjoie1wiSWRcIjo3OCxcIkZpcnN0TmFtZVwiOm51bGwsXCJMYXN0TmFtZVwiOm51bGwsXCJVc2VyTmFtZVwiOlwiR2F0bGluZyAxXCJ9IiwidW5pcXVlX25hbWUiOiJHYXRsaW5nIDEiLCJhdXRobWV0aG9kIjoiYXV0aGVudGljYXRpb24vZW1wbG95ZWUiLCJyb2xlIjoiQWRtaW4iLCJuYmYiOjE1OTIzNzUzNzQsImV4cCI6MTU5NDk2NzM3NCwiaWF0IjoxNTkyMzc1Mzc0fQ.UPrQNogh7PR4NqLSEBsBeNCnlCPA8ATZ6ttQZTcOO7A; Max-Age=172800; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 19 Jun 2020 06:29:34 GMT; HttpOnly
etag: W/"29-NA9GNaOnOGzxyvP55ORm4/m40kU"
access-control-expose-headers: x-total-count
x-vercel-cache: MISS
x-vercel-trace: bru1
server: Vercel
x-vercel-id: bru1::dub1::67695-1592375373291-bee974116ff3
strict-transport-security: max-age=63072000
cache-control: s-maxage=0

{"status":"ok","currentAuthority":"user"}
```

**Code:**

```
    .feed(jsonFileFeederAdmins)
    .feed(jsonFileFeederJourneySteps)
    .exec(
      http("request_0")
        .post("/auth/login")
        .headers(headers_0)
        .body(
          StringBody(
            """{
          "userName":  "${userName}",
        "password":  "${password}"
    }"""
          )
        )
        .check(header("set-cookie"))
        .check(regex("""id_token=([^;]+)""").find.saveAs("id_token"))
        // .saveAs("cookie")
        .resources(
          http("request_1")
            .get("${requestUrl}")
            .header(
              "authorization",
              "${id_token}"
            ),
          http("request_2")
            .get("${requestUrl}")
            .header(
              "authorization",
              "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjoie1wiSWRcIjo3OCxcIkZpcnN0TmFtZVwiOm51bGwsXCJMYXN0TmFtZVwiOm51bGwsXCJVc2VyTmFtZVwiOlwiR2F0bGluZyAxXCJ9IiwidW5pcXVlX25hbWUiOiJHYXRsaW5nIDEiLCJhdXRobWV0aG9kIjoiYXV0aGVudGljYXRpb24vZW1wbG95ZWUiLCJyb2xlIjoiQWRtaW4iLCJuYmYiOjE1OTIzMTAxNjksImV4cCI6MTU5NDkwMjE2OSwiaWF0IjoxNTkyMzEwMTY5fQ.Qwrsd0BFU-nX2oetz3E3J3cWmCqWgMzE_ia3ThUIw5Q")
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry Stéphane but I was working on other approaches.
This is my code that is working :)

```
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._

class Next extends Simulation {

  val httpProtocol = http
    .baseUrl("someBaseURL")
    .inferHtmlResources()
    .userAgentHeader(
      "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36"
    )
    .proxy(Proxy("localhost", 8080))

  val jsonFileFeederAdmins = jsonFile(
    "/home/lukasz/Gattling/Skeleton/user-files/resources/data/adminLoginTemplate.json"
  ).circular

  val jsonFileFeederJourneySteps = jsonFile(
    "/home/lukasz/Gattling/Skeleton/user-files/resources/data/userJourneySteps.json"
  ).random

  val jsonadminJourneyStepsSwagger = jsonFile(
    "/home/lukasz/Gattling/Skeleton/user-files/resources/data/adminJourneyStepsSwagger.json"
  ).circular

  val loginHeadres = Map(
    "accept" -> "application/json",
    "accept-encoding" -> "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language" -> "en-US,en;q=0.9,pl;q=0.8",
    "access-control-expose-headers" -> "x-total-count",
    "content-type" -> "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "sec-fetch-dest" -> "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode" -> "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site" -> "same-origin"
  )
  var token = ""

  def getToken() = {

    repeat(1) {
      feed(jsonFileFeederAdmins)
        .exec(
          http("Login admin and get token")
            .post("/auth/login")
            .headers(loginHeadres)
            .body(
              StringBody(
                """{
          "userName":  "${userName}",
        "password":  "${password}"
    }"""
              )
            )
            .check(
              header("set-cookie")
                .saveAs("token")
            )
        )
    }.exec(session => {
      token = session("token").as[String].slice(9, 380)
      println("Token: Bearer " + token)
      session
    })
  }

  def adminJourney() = {
    exec(_.set("token", token)) // Set it here
      .repeat(5) {
        feed(jsonadminJourneyStepsSwagger)
          .exec(
            http("${stepName}")
              .get(
                "${requestUrl}"
              )
              .header(
                "authorization",
                "Bearer " + "${token}"
              )
              .check(status.is(200))
          )
      }
  }
  val scn = scenario("Awesome journey")
    .exec(getToken())
    .exec(adminJourney())
    .pause(10)

  setUp(
    scn.inject(rampUsers(3) during (5 seconds))
  ).protocols(httpProtocol)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`regex` is applied on the response body. You want to use use [headerRegex](https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_check/#http-header) to apply a regex on a response header.

Comment: "no working as expected" is not exactly a useful followup. What have you done exactly and how doesn't it not work?